Variable Argument Processing - zsh vs. bash
I ran across a problem in one of my scripts when I changed it from bash to zsh. Here is the behavior in bash:
bash-5.2$ X="-v1d -v+1d"
bash-5.2$ echo $X
-v1d -v+1d
bash-5.2$ date $X
Mon Dec  2 12:01:24 CST 2024

And here is the behavior in zsh
~ > X="-v1d -v+1d"
~ > echo $X
-v1d -v+1d
~ > date $X
1d -v+1d: Cannot apply date adjustment
usage: date [-jnRu] [-I[date|hours|minutes|seconds]] [-f input_fmt]
            [-r filename|seconds] [-v[+|-]val[y|m|w|d|H|M|S]]
            [[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.SS] | new_date] [+output_fmt]
~ > 

How do I correct my code for zsh?
Thanks and apologies if I am posting this incorrectly. This is my first question.
